# How to place PlotLabel inside the plot frame

Tags: plotting, labeling, text

I have the following plot:

```
dibA1 = Show[Plot[{PDF[eϕ1rand, x], PDF[eϕ1fps, x], PDF[eϕ1grad, x], PDF[eϕ1rank, x]}, 
      {x, 0, 1200}, 
      Frame -> True, 
      Filling -> None, 
      PlotLegends -> Placed[{"No Stigmergy", "FPS", "Gradient", "Rank"}, {0.85, 0.7}],
      FrameLabel -> {"Minutes", "Probability"}, 
      AspectRatio -> 0.8,
      LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times", 12}, 
      PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, All}, 
      PlotStyle -> 
        {Directive[Thick, Opacity[0.45], {Black}, Dashing[{0.045, 0.020}]], 
         Directive[Thick, Opacity[0.75], {Red}],
         Directive[Thick, Opacity[0.75], {Blue}, DotDashed],
         Directive[Thick, Opacity[0.75], {Green}, Dashing[{0.025, 0.014}]]}, 
      PlotLabel -> "Event 1"], 
      ImageSize -> 600]
```

I would like to place it in the same relative position but into the plot frame. I have been testing

```
Epilog -> Text[Style["Event1", 12], {0, -1}]
```

in different parts of the code and trying other text positions but I can not see any text into the plot frame.

How can I get to see the text `"Event1"` into the frame and determine its location?

Comment: Use `Epilog -> Text[Style["Event1", 12], {45, -0.5}]]`. The `{45, -0.5}` are the coordinates (relative to the axes) where the text will appear.

Comment: Hi, Thank to answer me. I have tested the `Epilog[]` line but it does not show any text into the frame.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [scaled coordinates](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scaled.html) `Scaled[{x,y}]` for easier control. `Scale` runs $0<(x,y)<1$ independently of actual axes values, therefore not only it is easier to control, but also if you ever change the plot so axes values change,  `Scale` will faithfully keep your text in the originally specified location relative to the `Frame`. Remember `Style` works in `Text` and hence in `Epilog`. Also next time your ask a question try to give a minimal code example, no need to overload the question with irrelevant code.

```
Plot[Cos[x^2],{x,0,Pi},
    Frame->True,
    Epilog->Text[Style["Hey There",Red,Italic,20],Scaled[{.5,.9}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it works fine. I will remember your comment next times.

Answer (score 2):

```
Legended[Plot[x Cos[x] Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}, Frame -> True], 
 Placed[Style["Event 1", Red, Bold, 20], {Center, Top}]]
```

[image]

Use `Placed[Style["Event 1", Red, Bold, 20], {.7, .9}]` to get

[image]