# How do I put the PlotLabel inside the graph?

Tags: plotting, legending, labeling, plot-themes

I have this code:

```
basep = Plot[{p[x, y, t, baseta, f, basefa, baseul]*150}, {x, 0, basexhat}, PlotLabel -> "Rental price per m^2", PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.5]}]
baseq = Plot[{q[x, y, t, baseta, f, basefa, baseul]}, {x, 0, basexhat}, PlotLabel -> "Dwelling size", PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.5]}]
baser = Plot[{r[x, y, t, baseta, f, basefa, baseul]*150}, {x, 0, basexhat}, PlotLabel -> "Land rental price per m^2", PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.5]}]
baseh = Plot[{h[x, y, t, baseta, f, basefa, baseul]}, {x, 0, basexhat}, PlotLabel -> "Floor to area ratio", PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.5]}]
baseDen = Plot[{Den[x, y, t, baseta, f, basefa, baseul]*10}, {x, 0, basexhat}, PlotLabel -> "Population density", PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.5]}]
baseL = Plot[{L[x, y, t, baseta, f, basefa, baseul]/1000}, {x, 0, basexhat}, PlotLabel -> "Population (1000s)", PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.5]}, Epilog -> {Dashed, LightBlue, 
    Line[{{basexhat, 0}, {basexhat, 600}}], Dashed, LightBlue, 
    Line[{{lastxhat, 0}, {lastxhat, 600}}]}]
lastp = Plot[{p[x, y, t, lastta, f, lastfa, lastul]*150}, {x, 0, lastxhat}, PlotLabel -> "Rental price per m^2"]
lastq = Plot[{q[x, y, t, lastta, f, lastfa, lastul]}, {x, 0, lastxhat}, PlotLabel -> "Dwelling size"]
lastr = Plot[{r[x, y, t, lastta, f, lastfa, lastul]*150}, {x, 0, lastxhat}, PlotLabel -> "Land rental price per m^2"]
lasth = Plot[{h[x, y, t, lastta, f, lastfa, lastul]}, {x, 0, lastxhat}, PlotLabel -> "Floor to area ratio"]
lastDen = Plot[{Den[x, y, t, lastta, f, lastfa, lastul]*10}, {x, 0, lastxhat}, PlotLabel -> "Population density"]
lastL = Plot[{L[x, y, t, lastta, f, lastfa, lastul]/1000}, {x, 0, lastxhat}, PlotLabel -> "Population (1000s)"]


ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"][{
  {Show[basep, lastp, PlotRange -> {{0, 25}, All}, Frame -> True],
   Show[baseq, lastq, PlotRange -> {{0, 25}, {73, 78}}, 
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Frame -> True, 
    FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}}]},
  {Show[baser, lastr, PlotRange -> {{0, 25}, All}, Frame -> True],
   Show[baseh, lasth, PlotRange -> {{0, 25}, All}, Frame -> True, 
    FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}}]},
  {Show[baseDen, lastDen, PlotRange -> {{0, 25}, All}, Frame -> True],
   Show[baseL, lastL, PlotRange -> {{0, 25}, All}, Frame -> True, 
    FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}}]}}]
```

And I get this beautiful grid:

[image]

Except the labels are in odd locations. How do I move them within the graphs?

Comment: In each `Plot` use `Epilog` option to add `Text` where you want it.

Comment: @BobHanlon In one of the graphs I have two Epilogs: (how do I show this as code?) Epilog -> {Dashed, LightBlue, 
    Line[{{basexhat, 0}, {basexhat, 600}}], Dashed, LightBlue, 
    Line[{{lastxhat, 0}, {lastxhat, 600}}]}] Do I add a new Epilog after I or do I write it inside the {} or outside the {}?

Comment: You only need one `Epilog` per `Plot`, it can contain everything. `Epilog -> {Text[lbl, pos], ...}`

Comment: Similar to [153339](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/153339/how-to-place-plotlabel-inside-the-plot-frame).

Comment: @BobHanlon That worked. Is there a way I can change the font to be the same as the PlotLabel in terms of font, size and color?

Comment: Use `Style` for the label

Comment: @BobHanlon So 
Epilog -> {Text[lbl, pos, Style -> ...], ...} ?

Comment: Look in the documentation for Style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the `Epilog` based solution suggested by @BobHanlon in the comments, `ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"]` also supports labeling via the `PlotLabels` option and `Labeled` wrappers:

First, your plots with some dummy functions:

```
basexhat = 25;
lastxhat = 20;

basep = Plot[{x*150}, {x, 0, basexhat}, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.5]}];
baseq = Plot[{x}, {x, 0, basexhat}, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.5]}];
baser = Plot[{x*150}, {x, 0, basexhat}, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.5]}];
baseh = Plot[{x}, {x, 0, basexhat}, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.5]}];
baseDen = Plot[{x*10}, {x, 0, basexhat}, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.5]}];
baseL = Plot[{x/1000}, {x, 0, basexhat}, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.5]}, 
   Epilog -> {Dashed, LightBlue, 
     Line[{{basexhat, 0}, {basexhat, 600}}], Dashed, LightBlue, 
     Line[{{lastxhat, 0}, {lastxhat, 600}}]}];
lastp = Plot[{2 + x*150}, {x, 0, lastxhat}];
lastq = Plot[{2 + x}, {x, 0, lastxhat}];
lastr = Plot[{2 + x*150}, {x, 0, lastxhat}];
lasth = Plot[{2 + x}, {x, 0, lastxhat}];
lastDen = Plot[{2 + x*10}, {x, 0, lastxhat}];
lastL = Plot[{2 + x/1000}, {x, 0, lastxhat}];

grid = {{
    Show[basep, lastp, PlotRange -> {{0, 25}, All}, Frame -> True],
    Show[baseq, lastq, PlotRange -> {{0, 25}, {73, 78}}, 
     AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Frame -> True, 
     FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}}]
    }, {
    Show[baser, lastr, PlotRange -> {{0, 25}, All}, Frame -> True],
    Show[baseh, lasth, PlotRange -> {{0, 25}, All}, Frame -> True, 
     FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}}]
    }, {
    Show[baseDen, lastDen, PlotRange -> {{0, 25}, All}, Frame -> True],
    Show[baseL, lastL, PlotRange -> {{0, 25}, All}, Frame -> True, 
     FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}}]
    }};
```

You can now add labels to the plots by specifying them via the `PlotLabels` option:

```
ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"][grid,
 PlotLabels -> {"Rental price per m^2", "Dwelling size", 
   "Land rental price per m^2", "Floor to area ratio", 
   "Population density", "Population (1000s)"}
 ]
```

[image]

This puts them into the default position which is `{Left,Top}`. To put them into the center, use a [`Placed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Placed.html) wrapper:

```
ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"][
 grid,
 PlotLabels -> 
  Placed[{"Rental price per m^2", "Dwelling size", 
    "Land rental price per m^2", "Floor to area ratio", 
    "Population density", "Population (1000s)"}, {Center, Top}],
 LabelStyle -> {Red, FontSize -> 14}
 ]
```

[image]

Notice how I have also applied a custom style via the `LabelStyle` option.

Finally, you can also used `Labeled[plot, label, position]` for the indiviual plots to specify the labels:

```
ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"][{
  {
   Labeled[
    Show[basep, lastp, PlotRange -> {{0, 25}, All}, Frame -> True], 
    "Rental price per m^2", {Center, Top}],
   Labeled[
    Show[baseq, lastq, PlotRange -> {{0, 25}, {73, 78}}, 
     AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Frame -> True, 
     FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}}], 
    "Dwelling size", {Center, Top}]
   }, {
   Labeled[
    Show[baser, lastr, PlotRange -> {{0, 25}, All}, Frame -> True], 
    "Land rental price per m^2", {Center, Top}],
   Labeled[
    Show[baseh, lasth, PlotRange -> {{0, 25}, All}, Frame -> True, 
     FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}}], 
    "Floor to area ratio", {Center, Top}]
   }, {
   Labeled[
    Show[baseDen, lastDen, PlotRange -> {{0, 25}, All}, 
     Frame -> True], "Population density", {Center, Top}],
   Labeled[
    Show[baseL, lastL, PlotRange -> {{0, 25}, All}, Frame -> True, 
     FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}}], 
    "Population (1000s)", {Center, Top}]
   }},
 LabelStyle -> {Red, FontSize -> 14}
 ]

(* same result *)
```

(Notice how every `Show[...]` expression is wrapped in a [`Labeled`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Labeled.html) expression with the appropriate label and position specified)